# Quite-Off-The-Bat Complex Console Ant Colony Simulator w/ Partial AI

Tags: c++, simulation

As a [follow-up of my previous non-off-the-bat Ant Colony Simulator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116171/ant-colony-simulator), we have this one that works off-the-bat... quite; the code for when the ants find and take the food isn't really done but it would be almost impossible to do it anyway, if someone wants to contribute directly to the code, [please do it in GitHub](https://github.com/Gustavo6046/MyAntSim).

**scent.cpp**

```
#ifndef SCENT_CPP_INCLUDED
#define SCENT_CPP_INCLUDED

class AntScent
{
private:
    short power;
    short angle;
    short ScentType;
public:
    short addPower()
    {
        power += 1;
        return power;
    }
    short affectAngle(short vel)
    {
        angle = (vel + angle) / 2;
        return angle;
    }
    void ChangeType(short NewType)
    {
        ScentType = NewType;
    }
    short decreasePower()
    {
        power -= 1;
        return power;
    }
};

#endif // SCENT_CPP_INCLUDED
```

**antFactory.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "scent.cpp"
#include "randbool.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "foodFactory.cpp"
#include "board.cpp"
#include "tile.h"
#define DEBUG

#ifndef ANTFACTORY_CPP_INCLUDED
#define ANTFACTORY_CPP_INCLUDED

class Ant
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    Board* pertainingBoard;
    tile* Position;
    int index;
    AntScent NewDropScent;
    bool bFoundFood = false;
    short AntSize;
    bool bIsCarryingFood;
    std::pair<int, int> newPos;
    std::pair<bool, Food*> FoodPos;
public:
    Ant(int nx, int ny, int i, Board* pb)
    {
        x = nx;
        y = ny;
        index = i;
        pertainingBoard = pb;
        pertainingBoard->addAnt(this);
    }
    std::pair<int, int> moveThisAnt(std::pair<bool, bool> dir, std::pair<bool, bool> move)
    {
        if (move.first)
        {
            if (dir.first)
                x += 1;
            else
                x -= 1;
        }
        if (move.second)
        {
            if (dir.second)
                y += 1;
            else
                y -= 1;
        }
        #ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << "Ant moved to x:" << x << ", y:" << y << std::endl;
        #endif // DEBUG
        std::pair<int, int> result;
        result.first = x;
        result.second = y;
        return result;
    }
    void TickThisAnt()
    {
        if (! bFoundFood)
        {
            Wander();
            if (! pertainingBoard->bPosHasTile(x, y))
            {
                pertainingBoard->addTile(Position);
            }
            Position = pertainingBoard->PosTile(x, y).second;
            FoodPos = pertainingBoard->posHasFood(x, y);
            if (FoodPos.first)
            {
                FoodPos.second->BeTaken(AntSize);
                bIsCarryingFood = true;
                bFoundFood = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Wander();
        }
    }
    void FoundFood()
    {
        bFoundFood = true;
    }
    std::pair<int, int> Wander()
    {
        bool bool1 = MyRandomBoolean();
        bool bool2 = MyRandomBoolean();
        bool bool3 = MyRandomBoolean();
        bool bool4 = MyRandomBoolean();
        return moveThisAnt(std::pair<bool,bool>(bool1, bool2), std::pair<bool, bool>(bool3, bool4));
    }
    void resetFood()
    {
        bIsCarryingFood = false;
    }
};

class AntFactory
{
private:
    int foodAcumulated = 0;
    int XPos;
    int YPos;
    std::vector<Ant> AntGenerated;
    Board* MyBoard;
public:
    Ant* MakeAnt()
    {
        Ant z(XPos, YPos, AntGenerated.size() + 1, MyBoard);
        AntGenerated.push_back(z);
        return &AntGenerated[AntGenerated.size() - 1];
    }
    AntFactory(int nx, int ny, Board* PB)
    {
        MyBoard = PB;
        XPos = nx;
        YPos = ny;
        MyBoard->addAFactory(this);
    }
    Ant DelAnt(int AntIndex)
    {
        Ant theresult = AntGenerated[AntIndex];
        AntGenerated.erase(AntGenerated.begin() + AntIndex);
        return theresult;
    }
    void WeFoundFood()
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < AntGenerated.size(); i++)
            AntGenerated[i].FoundFood();
    }
    void TickAnts()
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < AntGenerated.size(); i++)
        {
            AntGenerated[i].TickThisAnt();
        }
    }
    void takeFood(int amount, Ant* giver) {
        foodAcumulated += amount;
        giver->resetFood();
        WeFoundFood();
    }
};

#endif //ANTFACTORY_CPP_INCLUDED
```

**food.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <utility>

class Food
{
private:
    short FoodSize;
    int x;
    int y;
    int index;
public:
    Food(int nx, int ny, int i, short ns)
    {
        x = nx;
        y = ny;
        index = i;
        FoodSize = ns;
    }
    short BeTaken(short BiteSize)
    {
        if (FoodSize > BiteSize)
        {
            FoodSize -= BiteSize;
            return BiteSize;
        }
        else
        {
            FoodSize = 0;
            return FoodSize;
        }
    }
    std::pair<int, int> getPos() {
        return std::pair<int, int>(x, y);
    }
};
```

**foodFactory.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "food.cpp"
#include "board.cpp"
#define DEBUG

FoodFactory::FoodFactory(int nx, int ny, Board* PB)
{
    XPos = nx;
    YPos = ny;
    MyBoard = PB;
    MyBoard->addFFactory(this);
}
Food* FoodFactory::SplatFood()
{
    XPos = -200 + (rand() % (int)(200 - -200 + 1));
    YPos = -200 + (rand() % (int)(200 - -200 + 1));
    Food z(XPos, YPos, (FoodGenerated.size() + 1), (5 + (rand() % (int)(50 - 5 + 1))));
    FoodGenerated.push_back(z);
    #ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "Food created at x:" << XPos << ", y:" << YPos << std::endl;
    #endif
    return &FoodGenerated[FoodGenerated.size()];
}

int FoodFactory::HowMuchFoodGenerated()
{
    return FoodGenerated.size();
}

std::pair<bool, Food*> FoodFactory::FindFoodAt(int xp, int yp)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < FoodGenerated.size(); i++)
        if (FoodGenerated[i].getPos().first == xp && FoodGenerated[i].getPos().second == yp)
            return std::pair<bool, Food*>(true, &FoodGenerated[i]);
    return std::pair<bool, Food*>(false, &FoodGenerated[0]);
}
```

**foodFactory.h**

```
#ifndef FOODFACTORY_H_INCLUDED
#define FOODFACTORY_H_INCLUDED
#include "food.cpp"

class FoodFactory
{
private:
    int XPos;
    int YPos;
    std::vector<Food> FoodGenerated;
    Board* MyBoard;
public:
    FoodFactory(int nx, int ny, Board* PB);
    Food* SplatFood();
    int HowMuchFoodGenerated();
    std::pair<bool, Food*> FindFoodAt(int xp, int yp);
};

#endif // FOODFACTORY_H_INCLUDED
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "scent.cpp"
#include "board.cpp"
#include "foodFactory.cpp"
#include "antFactory.cpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    Board Root;
    FoodFactory Feeder1(42, 21, &Root);
    Feeder1.SplatFood();
    AntFactory Anter1(-12, 95, &Root);
    Ant* Ant1 = Anter1.MakeAnt();
    Ant* Ant2 = Anter1.MakeAnt();
    Ant* Ant3 = Anter1.MakeAnt();
    while(true)
    {
        Anter1.TickAnts();
        if (! std::cin.good())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**tile.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include "board.cpp"
#include "antFactory.cpp"
#include "curses.h"

#ifndef TILE
#define TILE

class tile
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    AntScent tileScent;
    Board* MyBoard;
public:
    tile(int nx, int ny, Board* PB)
    {
        x = nx;
        y = ny;
        MyBoard = PB;
        MyBoard->addTile(this);
    }
    tile(Board* PB)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        MyBoard = PB;
    }
    std::pair<int, int> getPosition()
    {
        return std::pair<int, int>(x, y)
    }
    void changeScent(AntScent newscent)
    {
        tileScent = newscent;
    }
};

#endif // TILE
```

**randbool.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef RANDBOOL
#define RANDBOOL

#include <cstdlib>

bool MyRandomBoolean() {
    return rand() % 2 == 1;
}

#endif // RANDBOOL
```

**randbool.h**

```
#ifndef RANDBOOL_H_INCLUDED
#define RANDBOOL_H_INCLUDED

bool MyRandomBoolean();

#endif // RANDBOOL_H_INCLUDED
```

**tile.h**

```
#ifndef TILE_H_INCLUDED
#define TILE_H_INCLUDED
#include "scent.cpp"

class Board;
class tile
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    AntScent tileScent;
    Board* MyBoard;
public:
    tile(int nx, int ny, Board* PB);
    tile(Board* PB);
    std::pair<int, int> getPosition();
    void changeScent(AntScent newscent);
};

#endif // TILE_H_INCLUDED
```

**board.cpp**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "tile.h"
#include "foodFactory.h"

class AntFactory;
class Ant;

class Board
{
private:
    std::vector<tile*> BoardTiles;
    std::vector<FoodFactory*> FFactories;
    std::vector<AntFactory*> AFactories;
    std::vector<Ant*> BoardAnts;
public:
    void addAFactory(AntFactory* AFactory)
    {
        AFactories.push_back(AFactory);
    }
    bool bPosHasTile(int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < BoardTiles.size(); i++)
            if (BoardTiles[i]->getPosition().first == x && BoardTiles[i]->getPosition().second == y)
                return true;
        return false;
    }
    std::pair<bool, tile*> PosTile(int x, int y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BoardTiles.size(); i++)
            if (BoardTiles[i]->getPosition().first == x && BoardTiles[i]->getPosition().second == y)
                return std::pair<bool, tile*>(true, BoardTiles[i]);
        return std::pair<bool, tile*>(false, BoardTiles[0]);
    }
    void addFFactory(FoodFactory* FFactory)
    {
        FFactories.push_back(FFactory);
    }
    void addTile(tile* Tl)
    {
        BoardTiles.push_back(Tl);
    }
    void addAnt(Ant* mAnt)
    {
        BoardAnts.push_back(mAnt);
    }
    tile* getTile(int i)
    {
        return BoardTiles[i];
    }
    std::pair<bool, Food*> posHasFood(int x, int y)
    {
        std::pair<bool, Food*> result;
        for (int n = 0; n < FFactories.size(); n++)
        {
            result = FFactories[n]->FindFoodAt(x, y);
            if (result.first)
                return result;
            return FFactories[0]->FindFoodAt(x, y);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Compiler error discovered!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see a number of things that could help you improve your program.

### Don't use `#pragma once`

No doubt others will disagree on this one, but they can write their own reviews.  In my projects, I use `#include` guards instead.  The advantage is that it's specified in the standard, while any `#pragma` is, by definition, non-standard.  Some claim that it's faster to compile when using `#pragma once` but I'd recommend that you actually measure it both ways and see for yourself.

### Don't use `#pragma once` in a `.cpp` file

The use of `#pragma once` (or an `#include` guard) is for headers that might be included in multiple source files.  Neither should be used in `.cpp` files.

### Don't `#include` a `.cpp` file

Similar to the first two points, you shouldn't `#include` a `.cpp` file within a header file.  It is sometimes OK to `#include` a `.cpp` file within another `.cpp` file as for certain kinds of autogenerated source code but this project does not have such special cases and shouldn't `#include` any `.cpp` files within either `.h` or `.cpp` files.  To show how this should be done, here are `scent.cpp` and `scent.h` files rewritten to follow these conventions:

#### scent.h

```
#ifndef SCENT_H
#define SCENT_H 

class AntScent
{
private:
    short power;
    short angle;
    short ScentType;
public:
    short addPower();
    short affectAngle(short vel);
    void ChangeType(short NewType);
    short decreasePower();
};

#endif // SCENT_H
```

#### scent.cpp

```
#include "scent.h"

short AntScent::addPower()
{
    power += 1;
    return power;
}
short AntScent::affectAngle(short vel)
{
    angle = (vel + angle) / 2;
    return angle;
}
void AntScent::ChangeType(short NewType)
{
    ScentType = NewType;
}
short AntScent::decreasePower()
{
    power -= 1;
    return power;
}
```

### Rethink your classes

There are a lot of classes here, which isn't necessarily a bad sign, but they all seem to rely on each other.  In other words, the level of coupling is very high, which *is* a sign of trouble.  For example, the `Ant` class has pointers to both the `Board` it is on and the `tile` it is on as well as its own `x` and `y` coordinates and also its own `index` within a `vector` which is a private member of the `AntFactory` class!  That is just way too much information for a little `Ant` to track!  If we think about actual ants, individual ants probably don't actually have much concept of these things.  Instead, the `Board` should contain the collection of ants that is currently in the `AntFactory` class.  Next, the `AntFactory` shoul only generate a new `Ant` *and nothing else*.  The `Board` should also keep each `Ant`'s position rather than the `Ant` itself.  Similarly, a `Board` should include a collection of `tile` objects.  The `Board` should keep track of the positions of each `tile` and not each `tile`.

### Simplify your code

If we look at the `AntScent::addPower()` routine, it is currently this:

```
short AntScent::addPower()
{
    power += 1;
    return power;
}
```

However this could be both more idiomatic C++ and also shorter:

```
short AntScent::addPower()
{
    return ++power;
}
```

### Use a better random number generator

Modern C++ has much better random number generators than `rand()`.  A random variable that only has `true` or `false` values is called a Bernoulli distribution and it's already built into C++11's `<random>` header.  Use this:

```
#include <random>
bool MyRandomBoolean() {
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    static std::bernoulli_distribution d;   // default is 50:50 distribution

    return d(gen);
}
```

There's more, but it's all I have time for at the moment.

Comment: Very good! But I can't use C++11 because Code::Blocks compiler says its suport is still in experimental stage

Answer (score 2):

Let me offer some general comments as well.

First, `tile` should probably be renamed to `Tile` for consistency. Moreover, inside `tile`, I don't think you expect the `Board` to change, so do not use a pointer to a Board. Instead, use a (const) reference to a board you set in the constructor.

I strongly dislike the following function (the same goes for its counterpart):

```
short addPower()
{
    power += 1;
    return power;
}
```

I suggest the function *only* increments the variable (`++power`), and does nothing more. A separate const member function should retrieve the value of power for the user of the interface. Indeed, each function/class should have one task, and one responsibility.

Finally, your constructors should use member initializer list. So consider the following:

```
Ant(int nx, int ny, int i, Board* pb)
{
    x = nx;
    y = ny;
    index = i;
    pertainingBoard = pb;
    pertainingBoard->addAnt(this);
}
```

This could be rewritten as

```
Ant(int nx, int ny, int i, Board* pb)
: x(nx), y(ny), index(i), pertainingBoard(pb)
{
    pertainingBoard->addAnt(this);
}
```

The reason is that if you don't use the member initializer list, the variables will get a default value (e.g., an int is initialized to zero). So it's better to initialize them to the values you wish, instead of first initializing everything to zero, and then setting them again.

Comment: Good review! Something that everyone must read. It has different points from the other one, which makes this unique.